# Read a folder of JSON files and store in database using PHP

Tags: php, json, directory

I have a folder containing 175 .json files. Each of these .json files contains dictionary. I want to read all these files and load them in my database columnwise using php. Can suggest something?

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('bank_details')->delete();


    $dir = "database/data/bankdata" ;
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
       if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
         while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
           if(!is_dir($file)){
             $json = file_get_contents( $file ) ;
             $data = json_decode($json, true)   ; 

             foreach ($data as $obj) {

             DB::table('bank_details')->insert( array(
            'id' => $obj["id"],
            'name' => $obj["name"],
            'branch' => $obj["branch"],
            'contact' => $obj["contact"]
             ));
             } //end for  
            } // end if
           } // end whlile
         closedir($dh);
        }
}
```

I am using laravel homestead. This is the code i have written in seeder file. But, when I check my database table "bank_details" , it is having 0 rows . Nothing is getting filled in it. Why ?

Comment: I suggest you to write some code

Comment: read dir, get list of files, iterate over files, decode json, iterate over dictionary, insert into db, success :D

Comment: written the code. Can you suggest some edits?

Comment: just to check with your code example - there's 6 opening brackets and 5 closing - it's not case of it generating a parser error due to missing a closing bracket ?